# In a summary table, in one of the cells creating a formula to reference a sum row in a lower ranged table

Tags: excel

I have several tables, and one of them is a summary of the others
In the summary table, I want to fill in data from all the other tables.
If content start with '=' sign, the cell.Formula is used

```
Public Function AddTblAccount(oLo As ListObject, index As Long, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  Dim listrow As listrow
  Dim cell As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  
  With oLo
    If .ShowTotals = False Then: .ShowTotals = True
    If index > 0 And index <= .Range.Rows.Count Then
      Set listrow = .ListRows.Add(index)
    ElseIf (index = 0) Or (index = .Range.Count + 1) Then
      'At start the table has a empty row, if position is 1, use this row
      Set listrow = .ListRows.Add
    Else
      MsgBox ("Index is out of range")
      AddTblAccount = False
      Exit Function
    End If
    With listrow
      For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        cell = arr(i)
        'Check if the content is a string with a formula, start with '='
        If Left(CStr(cell), 1) = "=" Then
          .Range.Cells(1, i).Select
          .Range.Cells(1, i).Formula = cell
        Else
          .Range.Cells(1, i).Select
          .Range.Cells(1, i).Value = cell
        End If
      Next i
    End With
  End With
  AddTblAccount = True
End Function
```

Use the select statement only to verifies that correct cell in selected.
The content in cell is:

"=Income[[#Totals];[AccountName]]"
where 'Income' is the tableName, scope of tables are Workbook, refers to a table on another sheet
#Totals refer to SumRow in bottom of table
#AccountName is just the name of the column in Table

The Error result is 1004

I run the code above and when it start with '=' I expect the cell in table to display the summary result

If I do this manually, by go to table an select the cell, press '=' and choose the cell manually, I get formula result as above "=Income[[#Totals];[AccountName]]".

Comment: No one have made a comment, does that mean that the cell code suppose to be working?

Comment: I tried to use "=INDIRECT(Income[[#Totals];[Konto1]])" in cell, but it gave the same error

Comment: I tried to add the sheet codename to my formula like this "=" & shtIncome.CodeName & "!" & "Income[[#Totals];[AccountName]]" the same result

Comment: I'm using using Office 365 so there should not be any problems. Is there anything else I haven't tried?

Comment: Found the solution, by making the reference manually and then read the Formula back to a string variable, I found the way VisualBasic expect the format to be. The thing is that on my computer/Local settings use ';' semicolon to separate while writing code you have to use what VB use a separator and that is ',' a comma. By changing all semicolons to colon, made the whole difference

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.